# Java Mailx - issue with Chinese characters in openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, jakarta-mail

My usecase is to send a file in mail which has Chinese characters in it.
something like TW_TEST_1062054_COM_20191020_前端離岸風電設備製造股份有限公司_N_20201117

Reading through some posts, I realized some properties are missing and got it worked in my local machine.
However, I in Openshift, these properties have no effect. Please see my configuration below.

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("mail.mime.splitlongparameters", "false");
properties.put("mail.mime.encodefilename", "true");
properties.put("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");
properties.put(SMTP_CONNECT_TMOUT.getName(), SMTP_CONNECT_TMOUT.getValue());
properties.put(SMTP_READ_TMOUT.getName(), SMTP_READ_TMOUT.getValue());
properties.put(SMTP_WRITE_TMOUT.getName(), SMTP_WRITE_TMOUT.getValue());
log.info("Create Mail Sender instance with: hostname: '{}', port: '{}'", hostname, port);
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
mailSender.setHost(hostname);
mailSender.setPort(port);
```

Sending email with attachment as below

```
JavaMailSender mailSender = mailSenderRef.get();
MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true,"UTF-8");
ExternalMimeMessageUtils.updateFrom(mail, helper);
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, "application/pdf");
helper.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeWord(request.getFile()), dataSource);
mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
log.info("Email sent successfully");
mailBoxService.save(mailBoxItem.sentStatus());
```

Just reiterating, in my local machine all looks good. I have issue after I deploy to openshift as **spring boot app**. 
Mail attachment is shown as

> =ANSI_X3.4-1968QTW=5F1062055=5F1062053=5FCOMFWD=5F= =ANSI_X3

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the System property [`mail.mime.charset`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.charset) to "utf-8".

Comment: Thanks Bill. pleasure to see Chinese characters in the attachment now.